# Instance of a class in python

Tags: python

In the below code **Class B** inherits from **Class A**, and the variables of **Class A** are assigned through **Class B**. I have created two new instances of **Class B** using **Check1** and **Check2** as shown below:

```
class ClassA:
      def __init__(self, a, b):
          self.A = a
          self.B = b

   
class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        ClassA.A = a
        ClassA.B = b

    def printB(self):
        print("B = "+str(ClassA.A + ClassA.B))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('#### Part I - using Check1 ######')
    Check1 = ClassB(1,2)
    Check1.printB()
    print('#### Part II -  Using Check2 ######')
    Check2 = ClassB(5,6)
    Check2.printB()
    print('#### Part III -  Again Using Check1 ######')
    Check1.printB()
```

I get the following output:

```
#### Part I - using Check1 ######
B = 3
#### Part II -  Using Check2 ######
B = 11
#### Part III -  Again Using Check1 ######
B = 11
```

My question is why do I get **B=11** when calling the **Check1** in **Part III** ? Shouldn't python be creating a new instance of even the parent class for **Check1** object, and shouldn't **Check1** display the output as **B=3** ?

How can I modify the above code so that **Check1** can have value as **B=3** when I call it in **Part III**?

Comment: you are assigning values to clsss variables not object variables. you need to create and instance of class A in class B's init and then assign

Comment: You're assigning class variables (not instance variables) in your `ClassB` constructor.  Whatever value you passed in last is now shared by the entire class.

Comment: There is only one `ClassA` here.  Every reference to `ClassA.A` (for example) is to exactly the same class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be under the impression that a Python object has separate instance variable namespaces for each of its classes, or that Python objects have C++-style base class subobjects. That's not how Python works.

When you create an instance of `ClassB`, you're only making one object, which is an instance of both `ClassA` and `ClassB`. There's no separate `ClassA` instance. When your `ClassB.__init__` does

```
ClassA.A = a
ClassA.B = b
```

that doesn't mean "set the instance variables declared in ClassA", or "set the instance variables on some instance of ClassA attached to this object". This line assigns to *class variables* on `ClassA`, not instance variables on any object. (Also, you never delegated to the superclass constructor, so `ClassA.__init__` gets skipped entirely.)

Class variables are global state - separate instances don't get separate copies. Creating `Check2` overwrites the values set when creating `Check1`.

---

It looks like the behavior you want from `ClassB`'s constructor is exactly the behavior of `ClassA`'s constructor, so you can just inherit `__init__`. You don't need to write a separate `__init__`.

As for `printB`, that needs to access instance variables:

```
class ClassB(ClassA):
    def printB(self):
        print("B = "+str(self.A + self.B))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not implementing inheritance correctly -- assigning to `ClassA`'s members overwrites the class object iself, not the inherited instance attributes (which are still accessed via `self`).  In addition, you don't want to copy and paste the parent constructor; instead you should just call it directly.

```
class ClassA:
      def __init__(self, a, b):
          self.A = a
          self.B = b

   
class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        ClassA.__init__(self, a, b)

    def printB(self):
        print("B = "+str(self.A + self.B))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do in `ClassB`'s `__init__` method, `super()` can do for you (also what you're doing is not correct as others have pointed out). This way you don't have to repeat code and can initialise attributes only in the base class:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.A = a
        self.B = b

class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a=a, b=b)

    def printB(self):
        print("B = "+str(self.A + self.B))
```

And the output:

```
Check1 = ClassB(1,2)
Check1.printB()
B = 3

Check2 = ClassB(5,6)
Check2.printB()
B = 11

Check1.printB()
B = 3
```